Signal R not catching Identity IDs in blazor server
I am trying to implement a chat feature in a blazor solution (.NET 8), the chat is very simple, every user must be able to message every user in a application similar to whatsapp web, this is the Hub
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ChatService _chatService;

    public ChatHub(ChatService chatService)
    {
        _chatService = chatService;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string receiverId, string message)
    {
        var senderId = Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
   
        await _chatService.SaveMessageAsync(senderId, receiverId, message);
        await Clients.User(receiverId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", senderId, message);
    }
}

the problem I am having is that the line:
 var senderId = Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;


is always returning null, after some research I found out that ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier in this context could not be returning null as the id it's going to return is the id I need to point to the signal R client I am trying to connect, therefore hardcoding the Identity ID or using the connection Id from Signal R also did not work
I tried setting the Identity Ids to Signal R IDs using this
public class NameIdentifierUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
  public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
  {
    return connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
  }
}

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameIdentifierUserIdProvider>();

I tried hardcoding the Identity IDs in the hub for testing also without success
tried also using the signal R connection IDs directly like this
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var userId = Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
    {
        _userConnectionMap.TryAdd(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
    }
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public async Task SendMessage(string receiverId, string senderId, string message)
{
    await _chatService.SaveMessageAsync(senderId, receiverId, message);
    
    if (_userConnectionMap.TryGetValue(receiverId, out string connectionId))
    {
        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", senderId, message);
    }
}


Use [Authorize] attribute on the hub and methods. You may have to setup middleware to forward the auth to the hub as it does not use the same protocols as an API. I'm not sure in .net 8. This was the case in earlier versions.

How is authentication configured in your project? If there are multiple authentication schemes?
